# BLDC motor controll modebus rtu with python

Tags: real-time

```
from pymodbus.client.serial import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# crc16_table = [0x0000, 0xc0c1, 0xc181, 0x0140, 0xc301, 0x03c0, 0x0280, 0xc241, 
#     0xc601, 0x06c0, 0x0780, 0xc741, 0x0500, 0xc5c1, 0xc481, 0x0440, 
#     0xcc01, 0x0cc0, 0x0d80, 0xcd41, 0x0f00, 0xcfc1, 0xce81, 0x0e40, 
#     0x0a00, 0xcac1, 0xcb81, 0x0b40, 0xc901, 0x09c0, 0x0880, 0xc841, 
#     0xd801, 0x18c0, 0x1980, 0xd941, 0x1b00, 0xdbc1, 0xda81, 0x1a40, 
#     0x1e00, 0xdec1, 0xdf81, 0x1f40, 0xdd01, 0x1dc0, 0x1c80, 0xdc41, 
#     0x1400, 0xd4c1, 0xd581, 0x1540, 0xd701, 0x17c0, 0x1680, 0xd641, 
#     0xd201, 0x12c0, 0x1380, 0xd341, 0x1100, 0xd1c1, 0xd081, 0x1040, 
#     0xf001, 0x30c0, 0x3180, 0xf141, 0x3300, 0xf3c1, 0xf281, 0x3240, 
#     0x3600, 0xf6c1, 0xf781, 0x3740, 0xf501, 0x35c0, 0x3480, 0xf441, 
#     0x3c00, 0xfcc1, 0xfd81, 0x3d40, 0xff01, 0x3fc0, 0x3e80, 0xfe41, 
#     0xfa01, 0x3ac0, 0x3b80, 0xfb41, 0x3900, 0xf9c1, 0xf881, 0x3840, 
#     0x2800, 0xe8c1, 0xe981, 0x2940, 0xeb01, 0x2bc0, 0x2a80, 0xea41, 
#     0xee01, 0x2ec0, 0x2f80, 0xef41, 0x2d00, 0xedc1, 0xec81, 0x2c40, 
#     0xe401, 0x24c0, 0x2580, 0xe541, 0x2700, 0xe7c1, 0xe681, 0x2640, 
#     0x2200, 0xe2c1, 0xe381, 0x2340, 0xe101, 0x21c0, 0x2080, 0xe041, 
#     0xa001, 0x60c0, 0x6180, 0xa141, 0x6300, 0xa3c1, 0xa281, 0x6240, 
#     0x6600, 0xa6c1, 0xa781, 0x6740, 0xa501, 0x65c0, 0x6480, 0xa441, 
#     0x6c00, 0xacc1, 0xad81, 0x6d40, 0xaf01, 0x6fc0, 0x6e80, 0xae41, 
#     0xaa01, 0x6ac0, 0x6b80, 0xab41, 0x6900, 0xa9c1, 0xa881, 0x6840, 
#     0x7800, 0xb8c1, 0xb981, 0x7940, 0xbb01, 0x7bc0, 0x7a80, 0xba41, 
#     0xbe01, 0x7ec0, 0x7f80, 0xbf41, 0x7d00, 0xbdc1, 0xbc81, 0x7c40, 
#     0xb401, 0x74c0, 0x7580, 0xb541, 0x7700, 0xb7c1, 0xb681, 0x7640, 
#     0x7200, 0xb2c1, 0xb381, 0x7340, 0xb101, 0x71c0, 0x7080, 0xb041, 
#     0x5000, 0x90c1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53c0, 0x5280, 0x9241, 
#     0x9601, 0x56c0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95c1, 0x9481, 0x5440, 
#     0x9c01, 0x5cc0, 0x5d80, 0x9d41, 0x5f00, 0x9fc1, 0x9e81, 0x5e40, 
#     0x5a00, 0x9ac1, 0x9b81, 0x5b40, 0x9901, 0x59c0, 0x5880, 0x9841, 
#     0x8801, 0x48c0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4b00, 0x8bc1, 0x8a81, 0x4a40, 
#     0x4e00, 0x8ec1, 0x8f81, 0x4f40, 0x8d01, 0x4dc0, 0x4c80, 0x8c41, 
#     0x4400, 0x84c1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47c0, 0x4680, 0x8641, 
#     0x8201, 0x42c0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81c1, 0x8081, 0x4040]

# def crc16_modbus(init_crc, dat, len):
#     crc = [init_crc >> 8, init_crc & 0xFF]    
#     for b in dat:
#         tmp = crc16_table[crc[0] ^ b]
#         crc[0] = (tmp & 0xFF) ^ crc[1]
#         crc[1] = tmp>>8
    
#     return (crc[0]|crc[1]<<8)

client = ModbusClient(
  method = 'rtu'
  ,port='COM9'
  ,baudrate=19200
  ,parity = 'N'
  ,timeout=1
  )

connection = client.connect()

# read_holding_registers -> func 0x03
# read_input_registers -> func 0x04
# write_register -> func 0x06


registers = client.write_register(address=0x79, value=0x07D0, slave=0x01)  # start_address, count, slave_id
if registers.isError():
    print("Modbus Error:", registers)
else:
    print("Registers:", registers.registers)

client.close()
```

this is my code

and result is successful.

but BLDC motor is not working and using read_input_registers <- this func

Error
Modbus Error: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote slave/Unable to decode response

success result

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:SEND: 0x1 0x6 0x0 0x79 0x7 0xd0 0x5b 0xbf
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer -
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:New Transaction state "SENDING"
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Changing transaction state from "SENDING" to "WAITING FOR REPLY"
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Changing transaction state from "WAITING FOR REPLY" to "PROCESSING REPLY"
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:RECV: 0x1 0x6 0x0 0x79 0x7 0xd0 0x5b 0xbf
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Processing: 0x1 0x6 0x0 0x79 0x7 0xd0 0x5b 0xbf
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Getting Frame - 0x6 0x0 0x79 0x7 0xd0
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Factory Response[WriteSingleRegisterResponse': 6]
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Frame advanced, resetting header!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Adding transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Changing transaction state from "PROCESSING REPLY" to "TRANSACTION_COMPLETE"
Registers: []
```

and error result

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:SEND: 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x79 0x0 0x1 0xe0 0x13
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer -
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:New Transaction state "SENDING"
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Changing transaction state from "SENDING" to "WAITING FOR REPLY"
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Changing transaction state from "WAITING FOR REPLY" to "PROCESSING REPLY"
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:RECV: 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x79 0x0 0x1 0xe0
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Processing: 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x79 0x0 0x1 0xe0
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Frame check failed, ignoring!!
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Resetting frame - Current Frame in buffer - 0x1 0x4 0x0 0x79 0x0 0x1 0xe0
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Getting transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.logging:Changing transaction state from "PROCESSING REPLY" to "TRANSACTION_COMPLETE"
Modbus Error: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote slave/Unable to decode response
```

My English skills are not good enough. But as far as I know, there are the most smart people on this site. I beg you.